# What is the mandatory screenshot for App store portal?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

Currently, I need to deploy an app for iPhone and iPad, Lots of blogs and stacks confused still I don't get an exact answer, so somebody please provide mandatory resolution details. Among this 4 resolution which are mandatory
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've given the answer, yourself. To submit an app for the App Store, you will need to provide *at minimum* four sets of screen shots, as shown at App Store Connect:

- iPhone, 5.5-inch display. The iPhone 8 Plus is an example, 1242x2208.
- iPhone, 6.5-inch display. The iPhone 11 Pro Max is an example, 1242x2688.
- iPad Pro (2nd generation), 12.9-inch display. 2732x2048.
- iPad Pro (3rd generation), 12.9-inch display. 2732x2048.

The difference between the two iPad Pro models is that the 2nd generation has a bezel (with a home button) and the 3rd generation does not (so there is no home button; there's a home indicator on the screen instead).

If you like, you can also provide iPhone 5.8-inch, 4.7 inch, 4-inch, and 3.5 inch screenshots, and iPad 11-inch, 10.5-inch, and 9.7-inch screenshots. But those are all optional, because if you don't provide them, the Store will display them using the next larger required screen shot.